# Asynchronous Call not working in Coffee Script

Tags: google-maps, coffeescript

I am using CoffeeScript, Backbone.js and Google Maps API to reverse geocode a lat / lng

I have the function

```
  country: (origin, callback) ->
    @geocoder = new google.maps.Geocoder
    @geocoder.geocode(
        'latLng': origin,
        (results, status) => 
            if status is google.maps.GeocoderStatus.OK
              callback(result[6])
            else alert("Geocode was not successful for the following reason: " + status);
    )
```

When I call this I use:

```
@country(origin, (data) =>
   console.log(data.formatted_address)
)
```

btw:

```
origin = new google.maps.LatLng(origin_lat, origin_lng)
```

This does not work, it does not even seem to call it. I have the call back function under `(data)` but can not get it to work...

Thanks

Comment: Did you try to remove the key part (the stuff in front of the colon) where you use origin, i.e. not pass it as a key value pair, but just passing origin as an object?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure about the overall context of your question, but I will take a stab at it anyway.

The way you've defined your country function, it will typically be part of an object or map. If you just want a standalone function, try:

```
country = (origin, callback) ->
   ...
```

Then when calling it, try to replace `@country(...)` with `country(...)`.

Based on the comments, your call to geocode also looks wrong. You need to create an instance of GeocoderRequest and pass it instead of the `'latLng': origin` pair. Unfortunately I haven't used the Google style APIs much, so if this is your real question I'm not much use to you.

Comment: But the callback needs to be the function no so it needs to be open bracketed and closed after?

Comment: Not sure what you mean. Did you try the changes I suggested (leave everything else as-is)? If I understand the context correctly it should work...

Comment: No, wait, the call to geocode looks wrong. Does it take an object (key value pairs), or a list of parameters? Looks like an object from what you wrote, but then it needs a name, not just the value (the function itself).

Comment: the origin is a googlemaps-latlng. the callback was a function that accepts the outcode of the api call?

Comment: hey i saw your edit the function works... i can get a response from it inside itself - i just cant pass the result anywhere!

Comment: Make sure you get the result you expect before trying to pass parts of it (`result[6]`) anywhere, and I expect it will work when you figure out correct return values etc. Just keep debugging and trying.

Comment: Thanks! I got there in the end!